# How to wait until Kendo UI autocomplete is populated using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I use sendkeys method to enter a value in a Kendo UI autocomplete input field. Then, I tab off the field. After tabbing off the field, the entered value is disappeared.

How can I wait until the entered value is populated on the field before I tab off the field?

```
<td class="k-edit-cell" role="gridcell" tabindex="0" data-role="editable">
<span class="k-widget k-autocomplete k-header k-state-default" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="width: calc(100% - 30px);">
<td class="k-edit-cell" role="gridcell" tabindex="0" data-role="editable">
<input id="ddAssetID" class="k-input" style="width: 100%;" data-bind="value: AssetNumber" data-role="autocomplete" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-owns="ddAssetID_listbox" aria-autocomplete="both" type="text">
<span class="k-icon k-loading" style="display:none"></span>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the Kendo UI autocomplete box sample (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/index) you could use the following Java snippet to type "Aus" into the box, wait for the "Austria" element to be clickable, and then click on it so that "Austria" gets added:

```
driver.get("http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/index");

driver.findElement(By.id("countries")).sendKeys("Aus");
WebElement austria = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(), 'Austria')]")));
austria.click();        

assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("countries")).getText().contains("Austria"));
```